# with a CDC and NIH that are free from political influence

Tags: word-usage

Should "a" in the phrase "with a CDC and NIH that are free from political influence" be removed?  "that are" means "CDC + NIH" as plural and so "a" appears to be a mistake.

> Joe Biden tweeted just now:
> Our Administration will lead with science and scientists — **with a CDC and NIH that are free from political influence**, a Surgeon General who is independent and speaks directly to the people, and an FDA whose decisions are based on science and science alone.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is intentional and correct usage.  It is natural, especially in this context, but somewhat difficult to accurately explain the differences and reasons to do it.  It sounds more confident, for one thing, to list these things as factual objects in quick succession.

To confirm your understanding, if you wanted to use "the" instead, you would remove "that are" from the sentence.  Alternately, you could use a construction with "if the" and "were".  But if you change the construction on the first part, it doesn't match as well, and there is at least some pressure to reformulate them. (Necessity, in many cases)

And I see you are looking at this, so I'll rephrase the original to confirm that it is also normal:

> Joe Biden tweeted just now: Our Administration will lead with science and scientists — with the CDC and NIH free from political influence, the Surgeon General independent and speaking directly to the people, and the FDA with decisions (that are) based on science and science alone.

This is really fine, although I prefer the original.  Some small changes are possible; a comma after "independent", or a comma and the removal of "and"... change the last "with" to "having" or "making", or "making its", etc.

Comment: Thank you.  But how do you define "a" here?  Can such a definition be found in dictionaries?

Comment: it is for countable nouns

Comment: it is an article - the articles are "a", "an", and "the"

Comment: he is using "a" instead of "the" because right now, the CDC is not how he wants it.  He is asking us to think of two CDCs - one that is free from political influence, and one that is not.  He wants to make the first one a reality.

Comment: I'll talk about cars as a simple example.  I like black cars.  I have a car; the car is grey.  With a black car, I would be happier.  Now I've mentioned the imaginary black car, so I can use "the".  With the black car, I would be happier.  But before I introduced it, I had to us "a".

Comment: If "a CDC" being the case, why not "a CDC and an NIH"? The CDC and the NIH under Trump Administration are heavily influenced by politics. Biden wants both to be based on science and based on science alone.

Comment: It is equivalent to say "a CDC and an NIH", but not necessary, so we leave the "an" out to be more brief.  And I agree with the rest; I don't think I said otherwise.